# Get image src without loading the image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have a html snippet being returned through ajax.  The snippet is an `<img>` tag.

```
<img src="image.jpg" />
```

I need to extract the value of the `src` attribute without loading the image initially.  The reason for this is the `src` attribute contains a partial path that I need to manipulate in my app to load the image properly.

I have the following code currently extracting the `src` attribute:

```
var src = $(value).attr('src');
```

However, this causes the image to load, resulting in a 404.  I would like to avoid this unnecessary request.

How can I extract the value of the `src` attribute without causing the browser to load the image?

Comment: If you don't want to load the image, why even make a img element? Just create a string in the script with the value.

Comment: Make your server return `<img data-src="image.jpg" alt=""/>`. Then, with jQuery, get the `data-src`, manipulate it, and put it back as a `src`.

Comment: I don't have control over the server end - I'm just getting an arbitrary img tag snippet as part of an ajax request.

Comment: if you show your ajax function. You should manipulate it in either the `success` or the `done` part of the ajax before you even output it to the html

Comment: If you don't want to load the image, you will need to parse the return of the AJAX call as a string and use regex or something to extract the `src`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by changing the name of the src attribute before loading it into jquery.

```
 value = value.replace('src', 'data-src');
 var src = $(value).attr('data-src');
```

Doing this allows me to extract the value without causing the browser to attempt to load the images.

Comment: I would be amazed if the image didn't at least start loading if you are able to use `.attr()` on it.  That means it has created an `Image` object and has a `.src` property set on it.

Comment: Right, that's what was causing the initial load attempt.  by replacing the attribute name, the element no longer has a src attribute, and so it no longer attempts to load the image.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is probably to output a data tag on the image. You can then manipulate this using jQuery and then use it to write the final image path.

So you'd do something like this in your HTML:

```
<img data-img-src="abc.jpg" class="my-image" />
```

Then in your jQuery:

```
var path = $('.my-image').data('img-src');
console.log(path); // Do something here, then write the new path with:
$('.my-image).attr('src', new_path);
```

EDIT: Sorry I just re-read the bit where it's coming via AJAX. In that case, you can probably use the data callback of your ajax request to strip the src from the image.

Comment: That was my first thought, but I don't have control over the server to control what the attribute name is.

Comment: I suppose I could do a replace on the string for the attribute name before I load it into jquery...

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax('someURL.html', function(data){
    var html = data.replace(/\ssrc/g, ' data-src'),
        img  = $(html),
        src = 'some/path/' + img.data('src');
    img.attr('src', src);
    $('#container').append(img);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just have the string , like `<img src="image.jpg" />` why dont you go for regex?

Something like: `/[\"\'][a-z0-9A-Z\.]*/`.
PS:My regex skills are poor,so you could manipulate it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var string = '<img src="image.png">';

var matches = string.match(/src\=("|')(.*?)\1/);

console.log(matches[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply remove the attribute after accessing it.

This will not load the invalid image, as you can confirm in your console:

```js
var s= $('<img src="invalidURL.jpg">'),
    src= s.attr('src');

s.removeAttr('src');
console.log(src);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Remove `removeAttr()`, and it *will* attempt to load the image.

Comment: Interesting.  This is helpful. Thanks!